# Jquery Mobile Display Popup on anchor click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this code in my html page:

```
 <div data-role="content">
 <div class="content-primary">  
 <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="add" data-split-theme="d" 
      id="itemsMenu">
 </ul>

 <div data-role="popup" id="previewImg" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" 
      class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px;">
    <h3>Image Preview</h3>   
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" 
            data-inline="true"  data-mini="true">Cancel</a> 
 </div>

 <a href='#previewImg' id='tmpImg'  data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" 
   data-transition="pop">
 </a>

  </div><!--/content-primary -->    
 </div>
```

Where `ul > itemsMenu` is populated dynamically. when I click a row on the list view I expect the popup to occur. click event of the listview works fine apart from this line

```
$("#tmpImg").click();
```

Is the problem with anchor click event or the poup itself??

**::Update::**
My binding script

```
$('body').on('vclick','.imgClass',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     alert("This one Fires");
     $("#tmpImg").click();         
 });
```

where `imgClass` is the class for my dynamically generated `listview` on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are setting a binding to an element that is not on the page yet (list item). You probably should use something like:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'your_row_selector', function(){
      // do sth
 })
```

Then you can add list items dynamically and delegate a binding to them through the document, which is always present. So, the problem should be with your event handling, not with the popup

**EDIT:**
Regarding the popup, two things I would do:

1) use

```
 $('#tmpImg').popup('open')
```

2) try not to bind to virtual events such as `vlick`. The [JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) state to use virtual events with caution, because their behavior is fast yet unpredictable. Try binding to `click` to see whether this works.